# Ohm's Law and induced fields

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, maxwell-equations

Consider a simple circuit: A battery and a resistor, where the resistor is connected between points A and B. We then have:

$$\int_{a}^{b}-\vec{E}.\vec{dl}= iR$$

Will the same expression hold if $\vec{E}$ is an "induced electric field"? For instance, Consider a *stationary* loop , containing a resistor enclosing an area A , and a changing magnetic field through the area.  Is the expression $i=A/R*(dB/dt)$ valid?

Answer (score 1):

The relation
$$\int\limits_a^b{-\vec{E}·d\vec{\ell}}=iR$$ isn't *always* valid, specifically when the electromotive force (EMF) along the circuit is *motional*.

Consider the following circuit where a resistive bar is sliding with velocity $\vec{v}$ in a constant, uniform magnetic field $\vec{B}$. All other wires are ideal (no resistance).
[image]
In this case, there is *no electric field* driving the current. The magnetic flux through the loop is changing, so (motional) EMF is induced along the loop, and there is some current $i$ through $R$. If current flows from $b$ to $a$ (to be consistent with your original question), we have
$$\int\limits_a^b{-\vec{f}_{mag}·d\vec{\ell}}=iR,$$
where $\vec{f}_{mag}$ is the force applied on per unit charge due to the magnetic field, i.e. $\vec{f}_{mag}=\vec{v}'\times\vec{B}$, where $\vec{v}'$ is the charge velocity. This yields
$$BvL=iR$$
where $L$ is the length of the bar.

In short, Ohm's law really states $\mathcal{E}=Ri$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is the EMF along the resistor.

To answer your second question: yes, $i=A\frac{dB}{dt}/R$ is still valid (provided that $\frac{dB}{dt}$ is constant or the self-inductance of the circuit is negligible). This is because $\mathcal{E} = A\frac{dB}{dt}$.

Comment: Well, In almost all textbooks I have seen, The explanation of motional EMF is  the fact that the magnetic force makes the electrons accumulate across the rod. These accumulated electrons create an electric field. There comes a time(steady state) when the net force on these electrons becomes zero: which will happen if E + VxB=0. Or, E=-VxB. So there *is* an electric field driving the current. the integral (of the said E) .dl across the conductor indeed gives Blv. So it seems that it is valid for motional EMF also..

Comment: There will be an E-field if the rod is not connected to a circuit, but not in this case. There will still be an E-field if the rest of the loop is resistive, but even then the E-field will point in the opposite direction than that of the current flow, so it's not the E-field driving the current *through the rod*, it is the magnetic component of the Lorentz force.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a stationary loop linking a variable magnetic field (not too fast changing, so that we are in magneto-quasistatic conditions), Ohm's law is still valid in all parts of the loop.
The only caveat is that, since the electric field is no longer conservative, voltage is now path dependent and you need to specify the path you are referring it too.

Using your notation

$$\int_{a}^{b}-\vec{E_{resistor}}.\vec{dl}= i R$$
$$\int_{b}^{a}-\vec{E_{copper}}.\vec{dl}= i r_{copper}$$

The two voltages are different because they are computed on different paths: one inside the resistor where the field is strong, the other inside the highly conductive copper where the field is very small.
I went around the ring in the same direction so that it is clear that when you sum the two integrals you find a nonzero result for the circulation, in accordance with Faraday's law.

So in a loop with an almost full circle of copper wire and a resistor you will find that the voltage *along* the path going through the resistor will be the almost full EMF, while the voltage *along* the copper wire will be nearly zero. In both arcs, ohm's law is satisfied both in its local and integral form.

You must surrender KVL, tho.